# What to do about [preload] and [preloading]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

It looks like [preload](/questions/tagged/preload) and [preloading](/questions/tagged/preloading) refer to the same concept. Should one be made synonym of the other, or should it be blacklisted?

Comment: This has a [completely different definition](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Preloading) where I'm from... :-).